# Retrieve the access token from POST request and use in GET request

Tags: python, python-requests, oauth-2.0

I am using the requests library to make a POST request in order to obtain an access token.  My request works properly, but, I'm not sure how to extract it and then use it in a GET request.

```
url = 'https://login.insideview.com/Auth/login/v1/token'
payload = {'clientId' : '****', 'clientSecret' : '****','grantType':'cred'}
headers = { 'Accept' : 'application/json'}
r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, params=payload)

solution:  
data = json.loads(r.text)
data['accessTokenDetails']['accessToken']
```

Returns:

```
{"accessTokenDetails":{"accessToken":"the_access_token","tokenType":"bearer","expirationTime":"Fri, Mar 25, 2016 09:59:53 PM GMT","userInfo":{"userId":null,"firstName":null,"lastName":null,"userName":null,"companyName":null,"accountId":null,"role":null}}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it returns a `dict`, why not just access its contents as usual?

```
token = r['accessTokenDetails']['accessToken']
```

Comment: did not know that i could access like that.  Also had to use `json.loads` so i guess it isn't a dictionary.  Would you mind providing an explanation?  Bit of a beginner in Python.  Thx!

Comment: Using JSON to load the request's result is absolutely fine. And the result of JSON parsing is always a `dict` which you can use just as usual.

Answer (score 1):

@michael-queue the response from the request to a JSON endpoint is a JSON encoded string. To load it into a dictionary and access inner properties it's needed to `json.loads(json_string)` into Python. For the opposite operation, to dump a dictionary into a JSON string is `json.dumps(dictionary)` instead.